# Parsing JSON data into a List (Dart)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

for some reason I migrate from Firbase to Back4app realtime database for my flutter app. I have a shopping app and I store my product data into that database. Previously  In firebase I had a code like this to create a new product based on my JSON data , here I use foreach() method to add a product to my list because my response JSON body was <Map , Dynamic> :

```
    final List<Product> loadedProduct = [];
    var extractedData = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  extractedData.forEach((k,v) { 

loadedProduct.add(Product(
     id: k,
     title: v['Title'],
     description:v['Description'], 
     price: v['Price'], 
     imageUrl: v['ImageUrl']));

     });
```

but when I setup my Bakc4app It has a different type of JSON body :

```
{results: [{objectId: K9RTu0LBgI, pTitle: laptop, pDescription: macbookpro 2018, pPrice: 60.58, pImageUrl: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541807084-5c52b6b3adef?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8bGFwdG9wfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60, isFavorite: false, createdAt: 2021-06-11T10:42:39.185Z, updatedAt: 2021-06-11T10:42:39.185Z}, {objectId: CzzhXFKahu, pTitle: headphone, pDescription: best headphone for gaming , pPrice: 60.55, pImageUrl: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505740420928-5e560c06d30e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGVhZHBob25lfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60, isFavorite: false, createdAt: 2021-06-11T10:46:32.541Z, updatedAt: 2021-06-11T10:46:32.541Z}, {objectId: e5PiYuLDQZ, pTitle: apple watch, pDescription: apple watch seris 3, pPrice: 85.55, pImageUrl: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546868871-7041f2a55e12?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YXBwbGUlMjB3YXRjaHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=
```

and It contains a Map with a List of map how do I create a new product based on this type of JSON??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Product> loadedProduct;
    var responseBody= Map<String,dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(response.body));
    var resultList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(responsBody["results"]);
    loadedProducts = resultList.map((Map<String, dynamic> productMap){
      return Product(
     id: productMap["objectId"],
     title: productMap["pTitle"],
     description:productMap['pDescription'], 
     price: double.parse(productMap['pPrice']), 
     imageUrl: productMap['pImageUrl']));

    }).toList()
```

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'
 Products.updateProductListServer.<anonymous closure>
package:my_shop/providers/product_provider.dart:106
 MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:412:31)
 ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:341:26)

Comment: Can I see your `Product ` class may be you define price as a `String`.

Comment: `code`
class Product with ChangeNotifier {

final String id;
final String title;
final String description;
final double price;
final String imageUrl;
bool isFavorite;




Product({
  @required this.id,
  @required this.title,
  @required this.description,
  @required this.price,
  @required this.imageUrl,
  this.isFavorite = false,

  });
`code`

Comment: My Price is double

Comment: I have updated the answer try whether it solves the problem

Comment: still getting this error 
```
E/flutter ( 4305): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter ( 4305): #0      Products.updateProductListServer.<anonymous closure>
package:my_shop/providers/product_provider.dart:106
```

Comment: then it is may be a problem of your `updateProductListServer` method